# Htaccess Rewrite Rule But Not When File Extension Present

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a RewriteRule for paths but not for files. This code works for paths but if a file is requested such as an image or CSS file this is also pointed to the index.php file which is incorrect behavior!

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) index.php?$1/$2
```

Any ideas how to fix this!? Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this on the line before the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```